# Get time diff from now in moment.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I want to check when did my data get update. 
- When I hit 'Update' button, it shows 'Update now'
- When it is n mins away from my hit, it shows 'n mins ago'
- when it is n hours away from my hit, it shows 'n hours ago'

How could I do that in react?

```
this.state = {
    dataUpdate: null
}

handleUpdate() {
    const now = moment().format();
    getTimeDiff(now);
}

getTimeDiff(now) {
    cost timeDiff = moment(now).startOF('hour').fromNow();
    return timeDiff;
}

render() {
    return (
        <Data />
        <p>dataUpdate</p>
    )
}
```

Other question is `timeDiff` keep populating, should I put that in state?

Answer (score 0):

```
class MomentCounter extends Component {
  state = {
    dateUpdate: moment().format(),
    hourTimeDiff: null,
    minuteTimeDiff: null,
  }

  handleUpdate = () => {
    const nowMoment = moment();
    this.getTimeDiff(nowMoment);
  }

  getTimeDiff = (nowMoment) => {
    const updateMoment = moment(this.state.dateUpdate);
    const hourTimeDiff = moment.duration(nowMoment.diff(updateMoment)).as("hours");
    const minuteTimeDiff = moment.duration(nowMoment.diff(updateMoment)).as("minutes");
    this.setState({
      dateUpdate: moment(nowMoment).format(),
      hourTimeDiff: Number(hourTimeDiff).toFixed(),
      minuteTimeDiff: Number(minuteTimeDiff).toFixed(),
    })
  }

  renderMomentDiff = () => {
    if (!this.state.hourTimeDiff) {
      return  <div/>;
    }
    if (this.state.hourTimeDiff >= 1) {
      return  <div>{`${this.state.hourTimeDiff} hours and ${this.state.minuteTimeDiff} mins ago`}</div>;
    }
    return  <div>{`${this.state.minuteTimeDiff} mins ago`}</div>;
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderMomentDiff()}
        <button onClick={this.handleUpdate}>update</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```